# Send dictionary from raspberry to Laravel framework

Tags: python, php, laravel, dictionary

I need to send a dictionary written in Python on a Raspberry Pi4 to Laravel framework.
For creating the dictionary, I read from a file.txt and then convert the dictionary to a json format and the send via request.post method. Now, what I have to do to view the dictionary in Laravel view and then work with it?

The code in my raspberry for create and send dictionary:

```
def readFile():
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/device.txt", "r") as file:
        for i in file:
            line, *lines = i.split()
            if line in mac_dict:
                mac_dict[line] += lines
            else:
                mac_dict[line] = lines
    print(mac_dict)
    print("\n")

    json_obj = json.dumps(mac_dict, indent=4) #encode json
    print(json_obj)

    r = requests.post(ip, json=json_obj)
    print(r.text)
```

The route in web.php:

```
Route::get('dict', [DictionaryController::class, 'getDict'])->name('dict');
```

And the route in api.php:

```
Route::post('dictionary', [DictionaryController::class, 'getDict'])->name('dictionary');
```

The controller in laravel:

```
class DictionaryController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
       return view('backend.auth.user.dictionary');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function getDict(Request $request)
    {    
        echo $request;
    }
}
```

This is the view that I want to use for displaying the dict/json

```
@extends('backend.layouts.app')

@section('content')



@endsection
```

Someone can help me? I've been trying to figure this out for weeks

**UPDATE**

I forgot to say that I send the json in api/dictionary route, but I want to display it in route dict (that is in web.php)

Comment: It isn't clear from your python code exactly where you are sending the post request. It should be going to /api/dictionary. Have you verified that the request is being received by Laravel?

Comment: I send the request where I wrote requests.post and send it to api/dictionary.
How can I verify that the request reaches Laravel?